# Как ограничить вывод значения

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть переменная типа float, у которой после запятой много цифр.
Мне хотелось бы ограничить её до одного знака после запятой. Как это сделать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему комментарию, вы не совсем верно используете метод.
[Mathf.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) округляет значение до указанного количества знаков.
*Time.deltaTime* - возвращает время, потраченное на обработку кадра.

В итоге вы получаете следующую картину:
1. Объявляете переменную равную 0.
2. Прибавляете к ней deltaTime(а это очень малая величина)
3. Округляете переменную времени до одного знака после запятой (напомню, что ноль + очень малая величина = очень малая величина). Т.е. вы пытаетесь округлить 0.000031 до десятичных. В итоге вы получаете ноль и назначаете его в переменную времени. И дальше по кругу.

Надеюсь, я объяснил в чём проблема) Теперь о решении:
Вам нужно всегда хранить текущее время (вашу "second") целиком. А результат округления назначать в отдельную переменную и именно этот результат отображать. Т.е. примерно так:

```
float second = 0;

void Update()
{
    second += Time.deltaTime; 
    float cashSecond = Mathf.Round(second, 1); 
    Debug.Log (cashsecond);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Вы очень помогли. Если я хочу, что бы это значение округлялось до 2 знаков после запятой, как это сделать. Плюс компилятор ругается на дополнительный аргумент в виде "1", как это исправить.

Comment: @Лев, вы уверены, что ругается на второй аргумент? Если да, то вы используете *Mathf* (который из пространства имён UnityEngine), а не *Math* (который из System). Если второго у вас не видит - допишите в начале файла *using System;* Math не работает с float-ми, поэтому либо назначайте результат в переменную типа double и её отображайте, либо приводите к float, используя конструкцию: *float cashTime = (float)Math.Round(time, 2);*

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Math.Round

```
Math.Round(floatName, 1);
```

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Нужна ли дополнительная библиотека для этой функции?

Comment: нет, ну нужна...

Comment: second += Time.deltaTime;
second = Mathf.Round(second);
Debug.Log (second);   // в консоли выводит значение 0, хотя second может доходить до любых значений, как это исправить

Comment: вы забыли передать параметр, вам округляет к ближ целой second = Mathf.Round(second, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Ограничивать при вычислении нет смысла — ведь у двоичных дробей (а `float` представляет собой именно двоичную дробь) нет десятичных цифр.

Если вам нужно лишь *вывести* значение с 1 десятичной цифрой, используйте форматную строку. Например:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{f:0.0}");
```

или для старых версий языка

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0}", f);
```

Или используйте формат `0.#`, если вы не хотите выводить нулевую дробную часть.

---

Если вы реально хотите работать с десятичными цифрами, используйте не `float`, а `decimal`. В нём округление до одной десятичной цифры записывается так:

```
decimal.Round(d, 1)
```